# ToastContentBuilder - Failed initializing notifications

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications

I have a WPF application that needs to show notifications when certain actions are done. To do that I have the following function

```cs
        // using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
        void ShowNotification(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                new ToastContentBuilder().AddText(text).Show();
            }
            catch
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
```

The owner of this application gets errors by mail and today he sent me one with the following:

**Exception message**: Failed initializing notifications

**Inner exception**:
Metoden blev ikke fundet: 'Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationHistory Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.get_History()'.

**StackTrace**:

```
at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.ToastNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier() in /_/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications/Toasts/Compat/ToastNotificationManagerCompat.cs:linje 400 ved Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.ToastContentBuilder.Show(CustomizeToast customize) in /_/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications/Toasts/Builder/ToastContentBuilder.cs:linje 430 ved DinRevisor.WPFApp.Pages.ContentListPage.ShowNotification(String text) in C:\Users\MyName\Programming\CompanyName\AppName\src\ProjectName\Pages\ContentListPage.xaml.cs:line 736
```

Line 736 is the line containing the ToastContentBuilder. The actual exception is a *InvalidOperationException* and is caught by a global unhandled exception handler that sends a mail, and logs it to AppCenter

```cs
        public App()
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CustomExceptionHandler); 
        }
```

It works on regular machines just fine displaying notification. Even on the owners, who has notifications disabled, it works just fine. But one of their customers has this problem and I have no idea what to do about it. The only thing I know about the environment is that "it's a server", which most likely means a Windows server. But what versions and such I don't know. Other than that it's:

- .NET Framework 4.7.2
- Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications 7.1.3

Answer (score 0):

installing this windows 10 sdk (10.0.20348.0) in visual studio 2022 helped for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34898069)